# Call the property if the property present in JSON

Tags: json, angular, primeng

I am getting two different structure of data as JSON from server as below

JSON 1:

```
{
    [{
        name : 'sample1',
        code:'sample code 1',
        data : {
                   display :'test'
               }
        },{
        name : 'sample2',
        code:'sample code 2',
    }
    ]
}
```

I want to show the data.display property in UI.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items" > {{item.data.display}} </div>
```

if i call the data.display as above it throws error. How to overcome this

I want to show empty if data property is not present in JSON.

The same thing i am trying to use in ng-prime grid.If i try to set the headers and jsonNode,error occurs

```
let headers = [
            { jsonNode: "name", displayText: "Name", style: JSON.parse('{"width":"190px"}') },
            { jsonNode: "data.display", displayText: "Display name", style: JSON.parse('{"width":"190px"}') }
        ];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Elvis (`?`) operator:

```
 <div *ngFor="let item of items"> {{item.data?.display}} </div>
```

Here's [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/QLWuXUOzqYv9JpZYKhMc?p=preview) thanks to [Gopinath Shiva](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2877591/gopinath-shiva).

Solution for your `ng-prime grid`:

```
let headers = [ {
    jsonNode: "name",
    displayText: "Name",
    style: JSON.parse('{"width":"190px"}')
}, {
    jsonNode: data != undefined ? data.display : '',
    displayText: "Display",
    style: JSON.parse('{"width":"190px"}')
}
]
```

Comment: i try to assign the data.display value in ng-prime grid header.I give above example for easy understanding.

Comment: @sethupalaniyappan It's the same. If you can't make it work, post code here.

Comment: let headers = [
            { jsonNode: "name", displayText: "Name", style: JSON.parse('{"width":"190px"}') },
            { jsonNode: "data.display", displayText: "Display", style: JSON.parse('{"width":"190px"}') },
            { jsonNode: "exchange.code", displayText: "Exchange", style: JSON.parse('{"width":"190px"}') },
        ];

Comment: @sethupalaniyappan Check my answer, I just updated it, it should work.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the data in a `<span></span>` element and use the `*ngIf` directive:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items"> 
    <span *ngIf="item.data">{{item.data.display}}</span>
    <span *ngIf="!item.data">item.data is null</span>
</div>
```